# Multiple outputs after if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

```
if ((min(which((retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s))  == TRUE))) < (min(which((retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s)) == TRUE)))) {
  pos$open[i] <-  min(which(retail_stocks$ratio > (m + k*s)));
  pos$close[i] <- min(which(retail_stocks$ratio <= m))
} else {
  pos$open[i] <- min(which(retail_stocks$ratio < (m - k*s)))
}
```

If the condition is met, I want to fill the `pos$open` with the first index for which it's true, then I need to know where the closing point is, that's the first time the stockratio price crosses the mean again.

That can't be simply be `retailstock$ratio <= m`; because it should be later/higher index number than the opening point. Then I need to find the next open point which is either the first value in which the `ratio > mean + k *sd` or `ratio < mean - k*s`; after the last opening/closing index point and then I need to find next the closing point; which index needs to be higher than of the last opening point.

I have to repeat this until the end of the dataset. I'm kind of stuck on how to implement this.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(7306, 7307, 7308, 7309, 7312, 
7313, 7314, 7315, 7316, 7319, 7320, 7321, 7322, 7323, 7326, 7327, 
7328, 7329, 7330, 7333, 7334, 7335, 7336, 7337, 7340, 7341, 7342, 
7343, 7344, 7347, 7348, 7349, 7350, 7351, 7355, 7356, 7357, 7358, 
7361, 7362, 7363, 7364, 7365, 7368, 7369, 7370, 7371, 7372, 7375, 
7376, 7377, 7378, 7379, 7382, 7383, 7384, 7385, 7386, 7389, 7390, 
7391, 7392, 7393, 7396, 7397, 7398, 7399, 7400, 7403, 7404, 7405, 
7406, 7410, 7411, 7412, 7413, 7414, 7417, 7418, 7419, 7420, 7421, 
7424, 7425, 7426, 7427, 7428, 7431, 7432, 7433, 7434, 7435, 7438, 
7439, 7440, 7441, 7442, 7445, 7446, 7447, 7448, 7449, 7453, 7454, 
7455, 7456, 7459, 7460, 7461, 7462, 7463, 7466, 7467, 7468, 7469, 
7470, 7473, 7474, 7475, 7476, 7477, 7480, 7481, 7482, 7483, 7484, 
7487, 7488, 7490, 7491, 7494, 7495, 7496, 7497, 7498, 7501, 7502, 
7503, 7504, 7505, 7508, 7509, 7510, 7511, 7512, 7515, 7516, 7517, 
7518, 7519, 7522, 7523, 7524, 7525, 7526, 7529, 7530, 7531, 7532, 
7533, 7536, 7537, 7538, 7539, 7540, 7543, 7544, 7545, 7546, 7547, 
7551, 7552, 7553, 7554, 7557, 7558, 7559, 7560, 7561, 7564, 7565, 
7566, 7567, 7568, 7571, 7572, 7573, 7574, 7575, 7578, 7579, 7580, 
7581, 7582, 7585, 7586, 7587, 7588, 7589, 7592, 7593, 7594, 7595, 
7596, 7599, 7600, 7601, 7602, 7603, 7606, 7607, 7608, 7609, 7610, 
7613, 7614, 7615, 7616, 7617, 7620, 7621, 7622, 7623, 7624, 7627, 
7628, 7629, 7631, 7634, 7635, 7636, 7637, 7638, 7641, 7642, 7643, 
7644, 7645, 7648, 7649, 7650, 7651, 7652, 7655, 7656, 7657, 7658, 
7659, 7662, 7664, 7665, 7666, 7669, 7671, 7672, 7673, 7676, 7677, 
7678, 7679, 7680, 7683, 7684, 7685, 7686, 7687, 7690, 7691, 7692, 
7693, 7694, 7697, 7698, 7699, 7700, 7701, 7704, 7705, 7706, 7707, 
7708, 7711, 7712, 7713, 7714, 7715, 7719, 7720, 7721, 7722, 7725, 
7726, 7727, 7728, 7729, 7732, 7733, 7734, 7735, 7736, 7739, 7740, 
7741, 7742, 7743, 7746, 7747, 7748, 7749, 7750, 7753, 7754, 7755, 
7756, 7760, 7761, 7762, 7763, 7764, 7767, 7768, 7769, 7770, 7771, 
7774, 7775, 7776, 7777, 7778, 7781, 7782, 7783, 7784, 7785, 7788, 
7789, 7790, 7791, 7792, 7795, 7796, 7797, 7798, 7799, 7802, 7803, 
7804, 7805, 7806, 7809, 7810, 7811, 7812, 7813, 7817, 7818, 7819, 
7820, 7823, 7824, 7825, 7826, 7827, 7830, 7831, 7832, 7833, 7834, 
7837, 7838, 7839, 7840, 7841, 7844, 7845, 7846, 7847, 7848, 7851, 
7852, 7853, 7855, 7858, 7859, 7860, 7861, 7862, 7865, 7866, 7867, 
7868, 7869, 7872, 7873, 7874, 7875, 7876, 7879, 7880, 7881, 7882, 
7883, 7886, 7887, 7888, 7889, 7890, 7893, 7894, 7895, 7896, 7897, 
7900, 7901, 7902, 7903, 7904, 7907, 7908, 7909, 7910, 7911, 7915, 
7916, 7917, 7918, 7921, 7922, 7923, 7924, 7925, 7928, 7929, 7930, 
7931, 7932, 7935, 7936, 7937, 7938, 7939, 7942, 7943, 7944, 7945, 
7946, 7949, 7950, 7951, 7952, 7953, 7956, 7957, 7958, 7959, 7960, 
7963, 7964, 7965, 7966, 7967, 7970, 7971, 7972, 7973, 7974, 7977, 
7978, 7979, 7980, 7981, 7984, 7985, 7986, 7987, 7988, 7991, 7992, 
7993, 7994, 7995, 7998, 7999, 8000, 8002, 8005, 8006, 8007, 8008, 
8009, 8012, 8013, 8014, 8015, 8016, 8019, 8020, 8021, 8022, 8023
), class = "Date"), TGT = c(3.141479, 3.171741, 3.177794, 3.183848, 
3.214115, 3.171741, 3.171741, 3.1899, 3.099107, 3.050683, 3.038576, 
3.020419, 2.996207, 2.965943, 2.899359, 2.935676, 2.971996, 2.941731, 
2.881201, 2.905412, 2.881201, 2.887254, 2.935676, 2.990153, 3.014367, 
2.990153, 3.062788, 3.08095, 3.117266, 3.086999, 3.060472, 3.036135, 
3.060472, 3.030051, 2.999629, 3.005713, 3.005713, 2.969206, 2.969206, 
2.981376, 2.993544, 3.066557, 3.121317, 3.096982, 3.145654, 3.176078, 
3.243004, 3.212584, 3.206499, 3.291682, 3.261259, 3.279514, 3.334273, 
3.376864, 3.364695, 3.346442, 3.279514, 3.291682, 3.31602, 3.358611, 
3.352525, 3.352525, 3.352525, 3.340359, 3.401202, 3.407285, 3.407285, 
3.382949, 3.389032, 3.407285, 3.382949, 3.443792, 3.480301, 3.492468, 
3.443792, 3.364695, 3.261259, 3.279514, 3.267344, 3.309936, 3.358611, 
3.30385, 3.291682, 3.297766, 3.261259, 3.297766, 3.340359, 3.382949, 
3.340359, 3.31602, 3.328189, 3.443792, 3.49661, 3.514946, 3.527175, 
3.551625, 3.557739, 3.624979, 3.631094, 3.637206, 3.66777, 3.631094, 
3.649431, 3.692223, 3.698336, 3.692223, 3.710563, 3.58219, 3.551625, 
3.563849, 3.527175, 3.588302, 3.679997, 3.679997, 3.643319, 3.637206, 
3.563849, 3.631094, 3.612755, 3.588302, 3.606642, 3.490495, 3.453818, 
3.459932, 3.490495, 3.557739, 3.612755, 3.58219, 3.514946, 3.459932, 
3.447706, 3.47827, 3.557739, 3.692223, 3.790029, 3.820594, 3.716675, 
3.649431, 3.594414, 3.569965, 3.514946, 3.466044, 3.50272, 3.52106, 
3.52106, 3.508834, 3.423252, 3.325447, 3.288767, 3.264318, 3.154282, 
3.056476, 3.117604, 3.117604, 2.98312, 3.062589, 3.084957, 3.078812, 
2.998923, 2.900597, 2.876016, 2.826854, 2.789982, 2.667075, 2.716237, 
2.802273, 2.826854, 2.820709, 2.796126, 2.789982, 2.84529, 2.863727, 
2.814563, 2.826854, 2.771545, 2.789982, 2.7654, 2.697803, 2.66093, 
2.66093, 2.636347, 2.605622, 2.556459, 2.562605, 2.519587, 2.56875, 
2.544169, 2.48886, 2.593333, 2.581041, 2.64864, 2.562605, 2.556459, 
2.538024, 2.550313, 2.458134, 2.390535, 2.365954, 2.39668, 2.359808, 
2.316792, 2.353663, 2.495007, 2.544169, 2.636347, 2.605622, 2.599476, 
2.56875, 2.451988, 2.378246, 2.310645, 2.347518, 2.390535, 2.39668, 
2.445843, 2.421261, 2.372098, 2.329082, 2.347518, 2.427406, 2.525733, 
2.560616, 2.535875, 2.498765, 2.572986, 2.572986, 2.523506, 2.548246, 
2.572986, 2.647206, 2.653391, 2.696688, 2.690503, 2.739983, 2.808019, 
2.832759, 2.857498, 2.82039, 2.857498, 2.832759, 2.845129, 2.88224, 
2.876055, 2.845129, 2.89461, 2.851315, 2.801833, 2.826574, 2.826574, 
2.789464, 2.752355, 2.746168, 2.832759, 2.82039, 2.838944, 2.795648, 
2.764723, 2.727612, 2.702873, 2.715243, 2.721428, 2.696688, 2.709058, 
2.795648, 2.900795, 2.919349, 2.950275, 2.876055, 2.869869, 2.919349, 
3.01831, 2.975016, 3.024496, 3.117271, 3.240972, 3.253343, 3.315194, 
3.346119, 3.395601, 3.389413, 3.395601, 3.445082, 3.457451, 3.469139, 
3.444268, 3.475356, 3.444268, 3.357232, 3.338579, 3.3821, 3.419401, 
3.351015, 3.351015, 3.394534, 3.400749, 3.450488, 3.48779, 3.456703, 
3.425619, 3.425619, 3.369665, 3.313711, 3.388317, 3.3821, 3.326145, 
3.319927, 3.319927, 3.363447, 3.344796, 3.357232, 3.375881, 3.425619, 
3.444268, 3.481572, 3.512659, 3.68052, 3.668086, 3.767559, 3.649434, 
3.686734, 3.705388, 3.661867, 3.730256, 3.74269, 3.730256, 3.748907, 
3.767559, 3.78621, 3.724038, 3.761342, 3.817297, 3.873251, 3.873251, 
3.842166, 3.730256, 3.724038, 3.792429, 3.792429, 3.767559, 3.730256, 
3.711603, 3.68052, 3.755125, 3.730256, 3.717821, 3.685838, 3.6546, 
3.629611, 3.629611, 3.604621, 3.704578, 3.72332, 3.760802, 3.773298, 
3.767048, 3.823273, 3.89824, 3.998196, 3.923229, 3.885748, 3.860757, 
3.810779, 3.735816, 3.72332, 3.742062, 3.717072, 3.704578, 3.754556, 
3.710824, 3.692084, 3.667093, 3.648355, 3.660848, 3.604621, 3.567139, 
3.560891, 3.604621, 3.57339, 3.63586, 3.648355, 3.59213, 3.623364, 
3.629611, 3.617118, 3.604621, 3.623364, 3.510917, 3.510917, 3.492173, 
3.498419, 3.467186, 3.442196, 3.460939, 3.448444, 3.379726, 3.379726, 
3.342242, 3.335994, 3.45469, 3.442196, 3.379726, 3.348488, 3.342242, 
3.448444, 3.492173, 3.529658, 3.585882, 3.642108, 3.6546, 3.641291, 
3.672681, 3.729184, 3.635014, 3.603623, 3.785687, 3.879858, 3.898693, 
3.936362, 3.923805, 3.961475, 4.005419, 3.923805, 3.854748, 3.823357, 
3.823357, 3.798244, 3.810798, 3.766854, 3.766854, 3.798244, 3.785687, 
3.766854, 3.735462, 3.741742, 3.729184, 3.704073, 3.666405, 3.697794, 
3.666405, 3.609901, 3.67896, 3.666405, 3.685236, 3.641291, 3.540842, 
3.48434, 3.496896, 3.496896, 3.352498, 3.34622, 3.402724, 3.415282, 
3.503175, 3.528287, 3.509451, 3.515727, 3.48434, 3.365055, 3.239491, 
3.239491, 3.239491, 3.245772, 3.220658, 3.233216, 3.208102, 3.208102, 
3.132766, 3.051151, 2.950701, 3.139044, 3.139044, 3.120209, 3.214382, 
3.252049, 3.219725, 3.061896, 3.080835, 3.055584, 2.998765, 2.967199, 
2.973512, 2.979825, 2.967199, 2.92932, 2.897754, 2.979825, 2.998765, 
2.92932, 2.866186, 2.847248, 2.866186, 2.878815, 2.904067, 2.973512, 
3.055584, 3.055584, 2.986138, 3.024019, 2.916693, 2.94826), WMT = c(3.880284, 
3.880284, 3.859697, 3.818529, 3.869992, 3.767066, 3.767066, 3.808233, 
3.664141, 3.612676, 3.674432, 3.633262, 3.571507, 3.581798, 3.489166, 
3.489166, 3.509751, 3.447996, 3.468581, 3.489166, 3.458289, 3.509751, 
3.468581, 3.458289, 3.437705, 3.427412, 3.520044, 3.49946, 3.592091, 
3.530334, 3.540628, 3.540628, 3.581798, 3.530334, 3.437705, 3.427412, 
3.37595, 3.345068, 3.447996, 3.561214, 3.622971, 3.674432, 3.715603, 
3.695017, 3.767066, 3.725895, 3.797943, 3.797943, 3.82882, 3.777359, 
3.808233, 3.82882, 3.890575, 3.896348, 3.865425, 3.875732, 3.782961, 
3.834501, 3.855115, 3.896348, 3.916962, 3.906655, 3.896348, 3.88604, 
3.927274, 3.947886, 3.989117, 3.989117, 4.02004, 4.040657, 4.12312, 
4.236505, 4.215891, 4.164352, 4.071579, 4.061272, 4.050967, 4.009733, 
3.978813, 4.071579, 4.050967, 3.978813, 4.092195, 4.143735, 4.226199, 
4.102504, 4.174658, 4.226199, 4.236505, 4.236505, 4.288042, 4.411737, 
4.494201, 4.411737, 4.370506, 4.463278, 4.483892, 4.638509, 4.6282, 
4.638509, 4.617893, 4.545737, 4.741586, 4.679741, 4.648817, 4.813744, 
4.999286, 4.978668, 4.988974, 5.019899, 4.906511, 4.984531, 5.139329, 
5.18061, 5.190929, 5.18061, 5.10837, 5.10837, 5.09805, 5.139329, 
5.056772, 4.963892, 4.912291, 5.015491, 5.08773, 5.14965, 5.159974, 
5.18061, 5.10837, 5.159974, 5.40765, 5.510847, 5.572769, 5.696607, 
5.882366, 5.985564, 5.861725, 5.572769, 5.531487, 5.531487, 5.366369, 
5.366369, 5.490207, 5.38701, 5.221889, 5.242528, 5.18061, 5.036129, 
4.932932, 5.015491, 4.72653, 4.72653, 4.99485, 5.056772, 4.932932, 
5.015491, 5.036129, 4.99485, 4.809092, 4.623332, 4.66461, 4.520133, 
4.437573, 4.210537, 4.437573, 4.794697, 4.774029, 4.794697, 4.588029, 
4.712029, 4.753363, 4.691363, 4.546693, 4.629361, 4.464028, 4.422694, 
4.381361, 4.381361, 4.360693, 4.402028, 4.464028, 4.422694, 4.319359, 
4.360693, 4.278025, 4.360693, 4.381361, 4.360693, 4.505359, 4.774029, 
4.877362, 4.588029, 4.546693, 4.422694, 4.443359, 4.319359, 4.154026, 
4.195358, 4.298693, 4.278025, 4.216028, 4.13336, 4.360693, 4.588029, 
4.794697, 4.753363, 4.670693, 4.443359, 4.340029, 4.381361, 4.381361, 
4.422694, 4.464028, 4.588029, 4.691363, 4.588029, 4.402028, 4.546693, 
4.65003, 4.774029, 4.836029, 4.856698, 4.732694, 4.836029, 4.918696, 
4.918696, 4.89803, 4.89803, 4.877362, 4.856698, 4.89803, 4.877362, 
4.980697, 5.104698, 5.193252, 5.255322, 5.317395, 5.193252, 5.13118, 
5.007039, 5.089802, 5.04842, 5.007039, 4.98635, 5.13118, 5.11049, 
5.11049, 5.255322, 5.213944, 5.11049, 5.04842, 5.007039, 5.007039, 
4.965659, 4.965659, 4.903589, 4.800138, 4.820827, 4.717377, 4.800138, 
4.924278, 4.820827, 4.820827, 4.944969, 5.276013, 5.338085, 5.213944, 
5.151872, 5.089802, 5.234633, 5.213944, 5.255322, 5.296703, 5.400156, 
5.462226, 5.544987, 5.607059, 5.669127, 5.85534, 5.958793, 5.896721, 
6.103623, 5.938101, 6.124314, 5.979481, 6.145002, 6.082936, 5.938101, 
5.958793, 6.165695, 6.269146, 6.124314, 6.062241, 5.85534, 5.979481, 
5.938101, 6.124314, 6.04155, 6.062241, 6.000172, 6.04155, 6.000172, 
6.103623, 6.020862, 6.124314, 6.172701, 6.089849, 6.151985, 6.172701, 
6.151985, 6.255559, 6.586978, 6.483407, 6.421266, 6.421266, 6.628406, 
6.752683, 6.814828, 6.731968, 6.980535, 6.876967, 6.835541, 7.063393, 
7.2291, 7.332674, 7.270527, 7.249816, 7.104817, 6.959822, 7.00125, 
6.939107, 7.063393, 6.918396, 6.856256, 6.711261, 6.711261, 6.814828, 
6.856256, 6.856256, 6.814828, 6.752683, 6.628406, 6.959822, 6.628406, 
6.773399, 6.711261, 6.711261, 6.773399, 6.731968, 6.690542, 6.856256, 
6.897683, 6.752683, 6.856256, 6.980535, 6.876967, 7.00125, 7.104817, 
7.00125, 6.959822, 6.856256, 6.939107, 6.897683, 6.980535, 7.15338, 
7.049706, 7.070442, 7.194849, 7.091178, 7.049706, 7.028977, 7.132642, 
7.194849, 7.008237, 7.008237, 7.194849, 7.194849, 7.091178, 7.236314, 
7.236314, 7.194849, 7.257052, 7.505864, 7.402194, 7.402194, 7.588805, 
7.71321, 7.816881, 7.754677, 7.692473, 7.754677, 7.754677, 7.692473, 
7.63027, 7.5266, 7.671738, 7.671738, 7.754677, 7.837614, 7.899821, 
7.858348, 7.920557, 7.858348, 8.024223, 7.982757, 8.107162, 8.065692, 
8.148633, 8.273039, 8.542585, 8.252303, 8.024223, 7.879082, 8.065692, 
8.273039, 8.16937, 8.16937, 8.217847, 8.321602, 8.321602, 8.259345, 
8.404613, 8.259345, 8.300856, 8.383858, 8.342359, 8.238595, 8.197092, 
8.197092, 8.238595, 8.176338, 8.259345, 8.259345, 8.238595, 8.238595, 
8.238595, 8.176338, 8.217847, 7.948067, 7.885808, 7.927317, 7.927317, 
7.948067, 7.927317, 7.844307, 7.699036, 7.719791, 7.802801, 7.636783, 
7.761295, 7.802801, 7.927317, 8.031073, 8.051827, 8.051827, 8.134833, 
8.134833, 7.802801, 7.699036, 7.678287, 7.678287, 7.885808, 7.885808, 
7.823555, 7.678287, 7.636783, 7.678287, 7.699036, 7.782049, 8.114085, 
8.134833, 8.217847, 8.446115, 8.383858, 8.404613, 7.865057, 7.989568, 
7.885808, 7.844307, 7.844307, 7.823555, 7.927317, 8.072579, 8.072579, 
8.114085, 8.259345, 8.300856, 8.363108, 8.453169, 8.619324, 8.557015, 
8.598549, 8.557015, 8.598549, 8.743935, 8.82701, 8.847789, 8.82701, 
8.743935, 8.868549), ratio = c(0.809600276680779, 0.81739919036854, 
0.82332732336243, 0.833789137125841, 0.830522388676773, 0.841965869459149, 
0.841965869459149, 0.837632571326387, 0.845793598008374, 0.844438582369412, 
0.826951213139881, 0.831324303064299, 0.83891953732696, 0.82805981800202, 
0.830960464477758, 0.841368968974248, 0.846782578023341, 0.853171233377301, 
0.830656974710984, 0.832695262994079, 0.833129041557834, 0.822637845248851, 
0.846362244387546, 0.864633638195073, 0.876854471224262, 0.872422982705318, 
0.870099351030839, 0.880407262834837, 0.867813760842919, 0.874421230399163, 
0.864386769804679, 0.857513130439007, 0.854451311883026, 0.858290178776286, 
0.872567308713226, 0.876962851270871, 0.890331017935692, 0.887636962836032, 
0.861139630092378, 0.837179680861639, 0.826267723368473, 0.834566267657151, 
0.840056647602018, 0.838150947614044, 0.835040851421239, 0.85243357636219, 
0.853884326331385, 0.845874727451149, 0.837464022858217, 0.871424188169565, 
0.856370657992828, 0.856533866831034, 0.857012909402852, 0.866674126643719, 
0.870459263858437, 0.863434829859237, 0.866917211147564, 0.858438164444344, 
0.860161110628347, 0.861989483485561, 0.855899291338542, 0.858157426238048, 
0.860427508015198, 0.859579160276271, 0.86604652489233, 0.863065701491887, 
0.854145165458922, 0.848044567256363, 0.843034397667685, 0.843250243710367, 
0.820482789732048, 0.812885149433318, 0.825519682553463, 0.838658211409602, 
0.845812398580502, 0.828483046690791, 0.805056916040047, 0.817888373116115, 
0.821185614905752, 0.812936700970312, 0.829088708942828, 0.83036071310715, 
0.804380534163206, 0.795843846191902, 0.771676629519812, 0.803842238788798, 
0.800151533371117, 0.800470824965885, 0.788470449108404, 0.782725383305342, 
0.776155877204561, 0.780597755487238, 0.778027061984989, 0.796726096773221, 
0.807040420491357, 0.79574362161622, 0.793448860944911, 0.781496597290207, 
0.784558575688173, 0.784132573635192, 0.794251837363923, 0.79879104312458, 
0.769664622765463, 0.788980202109476, 0.795543468370555, 0.767016899943163, 
0.742218588814483, 0.719507707684063, 0.711894870568578, 0.709944363422451, 
0.718876407288193, 0.719887588220436, 0.716046199805461, 0.710340481140252, 
0.701862614572459, 0.702080643013081, 0.697648956516462, 0.710812646695521, 
0.708654289385157, 0.698204376485724, 0.713230100150847, 0.703177063481639, 
0.703097190292676, 0.689849109488981, 0.686061367250228, 0.690870059130232, 
0.700149845716277, 0.691461044162753, 0.68807584415381, 0.670532836018166, 
0.637560862851701, 0.631167949318862, 0.638414942374249, 0.64814423743818, 
0.644303499646231, 0.638301419882905, 0.634058233711066, 0.654868522273218, 
0.649809716627735, 0.645389747820071, 0.654995211846222, 0.645882532490777, 
0.637994159418761, 0.653620468497367, 0.674288557263473, 0.669301909307876, 
0.660781645404692, 0.660318073663324, 0.666696196095953, 0.650847145374202, 
0.6673568135609, 0.64666383160585, 0.624163688599257, 0.616520578740746, 
0.604735682551472, 0.610625958654895, 0.612565126906003, 0.616397289207884, 
0.623594433211093, 0.627382372713013, 0.616560870040582, 0.625391774976533, 
0.628717995174389, 0.633428705174661, 0.61209967700813, 0.58445257333258, 
0.592131719350678, 0.588297654679743, 0.609439478259619, 0.592097799058537, 
0.598584623139449, 0.610425371048883, 0.619035197670043, 0.610635895537203, 
0.620861921116982, 0.630833152824952, 0.631173738023413, 0.61574542704881, 
0.61020805638003, 0.604478208680181, 0.590575820760981, 0.589148152687027, 
0.591860736743577, 0.587660034769703, 0.588960326318804, 0.589069214457427, 
0.580680067221122, 0.570748731910272, 0.57561073379502, 0.540642086589755, 
0.543047655679443, 0.558541587248032, 0.56226778451943, 0.573863803374143, 
0.573960600527664, 0.569096942393536, 0.575474250762995, 0.563945675196253, 
0.557536907148289, 0.551611549722126, 0.549520069601056, 0.569430923026303, 
0.572158370240693, 0.554523304015733, 0.549846424080604, 0.548163899958829, 
0.55655038770478, 0.578109938899828, 0.56497041840043, 0.542809871179298, 
0.527380647246369, 0.530789152493932, 0.535510753964805, 0.522376820198826, 
0.521350191831244, 0.527734458522385, 0.53886481412658, 0.512258470057248, 
0.504839323617267, 0.508460673364154, 0.522274163368334, 0.527233935484562, 
0.535820612953214, 0.516697687296747, 0.523103277779314, 0.523103277779314, 
0.515208359279139, 0.520259369583281, 0.527536401850016, 0.545062921351091, 
0.541726163375888, 0.552898882633686, 0.540186042234651, 0.536757120597536, 
0.540705322984519, 0.539026723766879, 0.537386821930663, 0.543087452717488, 
0.556889058657073, 0.565755329646923, 0.558986184531343, 0.570919218290079, 
0.574402356362713, 0.570583492935715, 0.56412170300009, 0.557933779344055, 
0.548251341847846, 0.537849821571352, 0.542118212240101, 0.545831025987723, 
0.545191366803871, 0.54846147593418, 0.565755329646923, 0.567978993321934, 
0.571715456095556, 0.570122822283841, 0.575967399270604, 0.565797528100469, 
0.572960990821806, 0.565659362293334, 0.552655231893894, 0.559382861073422, 
0.561948810857556, 0.56535197692847, 0.54980816006329, 0.54689069207403, 
0.5658432464944, 0.558254358803945, 0.563846884417115, 0.557698887390959, 
0.5788919098479, 0.566095854830589, 0.571014836965561, 0.57725573113073, 
0.593342714124242, 0.586717876885915, 0.591253632251774, 0.590235321946395, 
0.579915256842472, 0.568808649671167, 0.575845626747475, 0.564432305206269, 
0.582248601025816, 0.566453483606491, 0.576014540392385, 0.565558156042911, 
0.566218023664888, 0.565371319888294, 0.560277727385395, 0.548535079986928, 
0.545433301441696, 0.547165772362423, 0.552768357444054, 0.57973303002046, 
0.568736483985817, 0.581076003927855, 0.569498885916039, 0.572154993337802, 
0.565074697624195, 0.570920133622836, 0.557748425486837, 0.552269334945732, 
0.555132091218609, 0.561730197436845, 0.543104909382504, 0.537840242059351, 
0.545157523610191, 0.546725487789713, 0.5418691104591, 0.545715244754335, 
0.539660963952222, 0.520059274526194, 0.531243526744503, 0.542194015946388, 
0.547035273106581, 0.555264719753135, 0.543204234524262, 0.552847261882472, 
0.542105072394878, 0.528144905798768, 0.538811368441931, 0.535709902113088, 
0.528111065036308, 0.517725581331009, 0.508717011011263, 0.515630710125965, 
0.519676499375984, 0.532907462641191, 0.535076615465166, 0.537238635957865, 
0.550113580897369, 0.548355584915069, 0.55984812086501, 0.560388351893512, 
0.555820433745611, 0.554893931259714, 0.556496656995598, 0.553134101177086, 
0.549506757040577, 0.547373462690474, 0.549648635956997, 0.555264719753135, 
0.539543252686635, 0.562768182878357, 0.548885574288478, 0.549202005405542, 
0.544547440488457, 0.5358625706237, 0.539160465409224, 0.5387636756484, 
0.540320839828618, 0.539792855079017, 0.556934480709371, 0.550343802798495, 
0.539650327661132, 0.555953373049485, 0.556792001428316, 0.562744402846688, 
0.560361221210498, 0.558311405090532, 0.563099890085784, 0.549174266948182, 
0.541604477909466, 0.533386051355663, 0.52311802252921, 0.527266243443344, 
0.523952816528302, 0.521839443746491, 0.523301488130745, 0.523721698465156, 
0.521710769575715, 0.511501208107739, 0.508815125932455, 0.514340625181483, 
0.508992347148077, 0.494922270085168, 0.501000229469722, 0.503920505168535, 
0.502446411253022, 0.504173119076922, 0.499264126321484, 0.499288691882048, 
0.483570046033341, 0.488654850170098, 0.486966566939478, 0.477461734752705, 
0.455182343019314, 0.449145509570889, 0.450331200126066, 0.454784696676868, 
0.44710901563018, 0.443886444270986, 0.449912401382494, 0.451942591808678, 
0.449037546833896, 0.440542416855216, 0.435656431437049, 0.430191225243811, 
0.44078338126884, 0.435730885547913, 0.430080978852044, 0.42275915696333, 
0.42531101956798, 0.429754257826583, 0.437464525100789, 0.435375289157908, 
0.444584544016806, 0.446959385703099, 0.441748189510529, 0.426251655675653, 
0.445049218381826, 0.46474082288092, 0.461349938990354, 0.446784107302882, 
0.457593273765541, 0.474927442385398, 0.477233005727492, 0.479001616846846, 
0.471520387540764, 0.476047160150173, 0.484956010434241, 0.466863257118442, 
0.466713522682489, 0.460597919057986, 0.456037900451081, 0.455296157837369, 
0.462554355445316, 0.4595354059708, 0.4595354059708, 0.461030551932702, 
0.46300519865984, 0.456071758716944, 0.452270973061423, 0.454172343706664, 
0.452648054674371, 0.449600083509385, 0.448416516049116, 0.449971142076507, 
0.461295180324977, 0.45777186053731, 0.464086398967015, 0.46250263487634, 
0.463664435642025, 0.459334602110651, 0.45139003356192, 0.452568347517793, 
0.452978066375113, 0.448159064930658, 0.438993487179091, 0.431141967931898, 
0.436090065605928, 0.43082445170289, 0.436202609539224, 0.438197070056274, 
0.435857725209446, 0.432181828440731, 0.42832348248575, 0.431262440244215, 
0.420765794574801, 0.421902828065687, 0.421902828065687, 0.411596630300915, 
0.408411921771364, 0.413266858864033, 0.417814806870334, 0.420085525541318, 
0.408003243431771, 0.396302991699221, 0.379167620250142, 0.386863583509416, 
0.385876882782966, 0.379686917996891, 0.380575211206572, 0.387894093626109, 
0.383090214861767, 0.389303726597277, 0.385607206797664, 0.387478873439475, 
0.382285522481463, 0.378261457640554, 0.380071719314302, 0.37589325619248, 
0.3675651857975, 0.362872881144923, 0.357126404271092, 0.360782241206778, 
0.361259730321789, 0.350266910340031, 0.339066449517335, 0.33033309804806, 
0.334951615721136, 0.334802418408036, 0.339378509912627, 0.345815555624559, 
0.349451820032971, 0.346162970247003, 0.337501041220581, 0.342587014175808, 
0.333567552823757, 0.332439951563666)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -500L))
```

[image]

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample input and desired output. `dput()` is the nicest way to share data because it is copy/pasteable.

Comment: Hi Gregor, i added the sample input head 500 i used because it's was too big.

Comment: That's a lot of data! How about just **a few** rows. Do you think 5 rows would illustrate the problem? If not, what about 10? And then with such a nice small sample input, you can also easily show the desired output, which will help make your question much more understandable.

Comment: I'm not sure, because the first opening point is at index 387;  the fist closing point is at 1743. So this make it a little bit hard. I'll add a picture, in which the greenpoints are the opening points and orange closing.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not the *first* 10 rows, but rows 383-383 and rows 1737-1747... in general, the smaller example you can construct, the easier your problem will be to understand, and the faster you'll get help.

Comment: Additionally, your code appears pulled out of a larger code block. Are you running the `if` inside a loop? Please provide enough context for us to take your posted data and run code.

Comment: I just tried something, because I'm stuck… I try to state the concept, if i could upload the dataset I would. I think the graph illustrates the concept quite well. the solid  line is the mean ratio; the dashed lines are the k*sd(ratio) either - or +. The objective is to write a function, in which you fined the first opening point; which is either m + k*sd or m - k*sd. The closing point is when it hits the mean again; so in the case of  m +k* sd it's  closing position <- ratio <= m ; finding the next opening point and closing point an so on.